# I am unable to put a condition in requestparams for comparing and getting an output from the entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/getTransactions",produces = {"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> getTransaction(@PathVariable String paymentService, @RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> requestParams) throws Exception {
    
        String loginId = SecurityContextUtils.getJWTUser().getUsername();
        requestParams.put("serviceProvider", paymentService);
        requestParams.put("loginId.loginId.loginId", loginId);
        ApiFilterResponse<PaymentTransaction> result = super.getResponse(requestParams);
        List<PaymentTransaction> paymentTransaction = (List<PaymentTransaction>) result.getFeatures();
        result.setFeatures(paymentTransaction);
        return ResponseEntityMapper.toResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

Comment: Basically i want to get entries from the DB by having two condition that is the service provider with a desired name and a loginid with a desired name. How can i put a condition while setting the requestparams

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: This is working fine just wanted to ask to get any options for comparing and i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/getTransactions",produces = {"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> getTransaction(@PathVariable String paymentService, @RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> requestParams) throws Exception {
        String loginId = SecurityContextUtils.getJWTUser().getUsername();
        String filter = requestParams.get("filter");
        if (filter != null) {
                filter = filter + " AND loginId.loginId:" + loginId+ " AND serviceProvider:" + paymentService;
            }else{
                filter = "loginId.loginId:" + loginId+ " AND serviceProvider:" + paymentService;
            }
        requestParams.put("filter", filter);
        ApiFilterResponse<PaymentTransaction> result = super.getResponse(requestParams);
        return ResponseEntityMapper.toResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```